# Cypress API request aborted when testing against localhost

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

Consider the test below for a registration workflow (a simplified version of my actual code).

On submitting the form an API request is made to POST /register/. When running cypress against the live URL (configured via `cypress.json` `baseUrl`) this request works fine. However, when running cypress against the localhost URL this request fails as "aborted".

(If I use the app manually over localhost I am able to register without any errors)

```js
// Visit the homepage
cy.visit('/');
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/');

// Click the link to register
cy.get('#register').click();
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/register/');

// Fill out the form
cy.get('#name').type('foo bar');
cy.get('#email').type('foo.bar@gmail.com');
cy.get('#password').type('qwerty123!');

// Submit the form
cy.get('#submit').click();  // <-- API REQUEST IS ABORTED

// A successful registration should redirect us to the homepage
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/');
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing regarding running cypress against localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run backend as well (application which handle `POST /register` request) ?

---

When you running cypress against the live URL the api request is going to "production" backend which is (in most cases) up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am running the backend locally too.
> (If I use the app manually over localhost I am able to register without any errors)

Comment: @peter554 could you show commands how you run your tests and app(usually it's a scripts section in `package.json`)? and also just for case show pls `cypress.json` config